# Get SharePoint user pictures from mysite

Tags: user-profile, my-site, csom, picture, core-api

I have written a SharePoint core solution with C# which gets the URLs of user pictures and should download them.

The URL I get is correct. The URL structure is like:

```
http://mytestsharepoint/my/username/thumb.png
```

But if I try to download the picture, I get a

> Http 401 Unauthorized exception.

Does someone know how to fix this? Do I have to set additional permissions in SharePoint to access the user pictures?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Basically the pictures are stored in a picture library where user don't have permission to access it . Using the Farm Admin credentials you can navigate to the below mentioned path and give a try!

```
http://mytestsharepoint/my/user photos/
```

Let me know if it works